# email looping in php

Tags: php, email, smtp

I use the code below to send email to many people from my database but it usually timeouts and does not send to all. Please tell me how can i set it in php so that it sends like only 1000 email per 10mins in php?

```
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = "xxx Support <$sender>";
$to = "$to";
$subject = "$subject";
$body = "Dear $fname,\n\n$note\n\n\nYou are getting this email because you registered on our website www.xxx.com and agreed to our Terms and Conditions which includes to receive email from us at any time to your email address $to.";

$host = "smtp1.xxx.net";
$username = "no_reply@xxx.net";
$password = "4t46546$#@?";

$headers = array ('From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
}

// Show sent emails.
echo "$row[fname] $row[lname] ($row[email])<br>";
}
```

Comment: Before looking for a different solution, have you tried set_time_limit(0) to prevent the timeout?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your script to pull recipients starting from a certain number, and until all recipients are served, output a META redirect to force the browser to reload from where it left off.

Imagine:

```
<?php
// Start from $x, or zero if no $x
$x = ( isset( $_REQUEST['x'] ) ? $_REQUEST['x'] : 0 ); 

// Count total number of recipients
$rs = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM recipients ');  
if ( $rs ) $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs );
$total = $row['total'];

// Pull recipients $x through $x+1000 from database  
$rs = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM recipients ORDER BY email ASC LIMIT ' . $x . ', 1000 ' );
// Count number of recipients in query result set
$num_recipients = mysql_num_rows( $rs ); 

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $rs ) ){
    // Send the message here...
}

if ( ( $num_recipients + $x) < $total ){
    // We've not yet reached the total # of recipients
    // Output the meta redirect to start from ($x+1000).
    echo '<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=this-script.php?x=' . ($x+1000) . '">';
} else {
    // We've finished, do something...
}
```